# Update AutoMapper extension method from v3 to v5

Tags: c#, automapper

I have been tasked with upgrading our code base from using Automapper 3.3 to 5.1. All is going well so far except for an extensions method that was defined which no longer works. The person who wrote (or copied?) this methods no longer works here and nobody can explain what exactly they are supposed to do, which makes it hard to update.

```
    public static void IgnoreIfSourceIsNull<T>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<T> expression)
    {
        expression.Condition(IgnoreIfSourceIsNull);
    }

    private static bool IgnoreIfSourceIsNull(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (!context.IsSourceValueNull)  // A
            return true;

        var result = context.GetContextPropertyMap().ResolveValue(context.Parent);
        return result.Value != null; //B
    }
```

Which was then called using:

`Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA,TypeB>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());`

This no longer works in AutoMapper 5. Aside from the fact that the `IMemberConfigurationExpression` interface was changed, the problem I have is that `ResolutionContext` no long contain an `IsSourceValueNull` property nor a `Parent` property. I am not exactly sure what this method is supposed to do. I *think* that it ignores the property if A. the property value is null or B. the parent object is null.

A. I understand; B. doesn't make so much sense to me (if the parent object is null why would we be mapping this particular property anyways?) so its proving to be difficult to translate this to something that can be called in version 5.

My *best guess* as to how to update this is :

```
    public static void IgnoreIfSourceIsNull<TSource,TDestination,TMember>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource,TDestination,TMember> expression)
    {
        // either this
        expression.Condition(c => c != null);
        // or this
        expression.Condition((src,dest,sMember,dMember) => sMember != null && src != null);
    }
```

However, since we aren't too sure what it was doing in the first place, it makes it difficult to say whether this correct or what exactly I should be testing after the change.

My question is therefore two-fold:

1. What *exactly* was this doing?
2. How would I get this to work in Automapper 5?

Comment: Also, if anyone knows where I can find the upgrade guide for version 4 that would be great. I have the version 5 upgrade guide (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide) but If one existed for version 4 I'd like to take a look at it to see if there's anything else I need to really be aware of when going from 3->5

Comment: Please show an example of the behavior you expect when mapping `TypeA` to `TypeB`.

Comment: That's the problem; we aren't entirely sure what the expected behavior is. We have a *lot* of types being mapped and only two of them make use of this old extension method. Nobody is around who worked on the original code so we don't know. I'm trying to figure out what it **was** doing before and what the replacement for it is now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what the desired behavior is. You would start with `TypeA objA` with some values already filled, then use automapper to update items, IFF the source property is not null.

The `IsSourceValueNull` property was removed in commit [ad5d39](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/ad5d39c8df2060fbd4abd717baeeb40ecbd25613#diff-fec1882a071af9ef9aa48cd54d415281L81)

In Automapper 5, there is a [unit test](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Bug/IgnoreAll.cs) that does exactly what you need.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
   .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcVal, destVal, c) => srcVal != null));
```

To clarify the comment about `src != null`:

```
if(null == newValueInstance) {
    // throw new CustomException("newObject should not be null")
    // Or just return the existing object unchanged.
    return existingObject;
}
return Mapper.Map(newValueInstance, existingObject);
```

Comment: Ok I think that may be what I was missing... The *update* part. I saw your suggestion somewhere else (don't recall where), but I wonder if it should be both a check on `src` and `srcVal` like I had in the code I posted above as one of the possibilities?

Comment: I'd actually move the null check outside the mapping. ex: an explicit return for dest object, if src itself is null, as opposed to its properties.

Comment: Not sure I follow that last comment

Comment: Ah OK I see what you mean. Don't think it's possible in this case as the object is actually part of a larger object graph and would get mapped as part of the parent map(s)